# fetch data from backend django and react

Tags: reactjs, django

i'm trying to fetch data from my backend and i'm resiving this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"
this my react app

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
 const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
     fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        'method':'GET',
        headers: {
         'Content-Type':'application/json',
         'Authorization':'token 2e8bfe0b7ff1716c0c255ac62adad9d9832e7173'
        }
       })
       .then(resp => resp.json())
       .then(resp => setArticles(resp))
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
 }, [])


 return (
              <div className="App">
                {articles.map(article => {
                  return ( <h2>{article.first_name}</h2> )
                })}
              </div>
          )
 }
```

export default App;

Comment: Does the server return the error or the react application receives the response and throws this error? If the error is in the response from the server it may be useful to share the backend code that you are trying to execute. Sounds like you have missed a bracket or something somewhere.

Comment: the problem was in my port url in my bakend i fix it thank you